# How to programmatically add spaces in SMS in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, sms

In my iPhone app, I have ASCII arts which I send to others via SMS.

Problem is when I send the ASCII art to SMS API then it trims the spaces in between the characters of the ASCII art. and becomes left aligned.

What could be wrong?

Comment: i am currently using that one. The ASCII art looks fine when shown in the label but then if I send that same ASCII art to SMS API, it trims all the spaces and becomes left aligned as I had mentioned. What can be done in that case?

Comment: I noticed a typo, I meant `[NSString stringWithFormat@"   "];`.  In answer to your question, I'm not sure if the SMS box strips formatting.  In that case it'd be impossible to add spaces once it's in the SMS box, as it's out of your sandbox.

Comment: but is there no way we can preformat the text so that spaces are not trimed by the SMS API?

Comment: Not really a solution, but could you use underscores instead of spaces?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the escape sequence for " " (space) in iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613736/what-is-the-escape-sequence-for-space-in-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution, refer to my question:

[How to Add spaces in SMS API in iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613736/what-is-the-escape-sequence-for-space-in-iphone-sdk/)

Refer to answer by **phix23**. That works in my case.