# What is the escape sequence for " " (space) in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

In my iPhone app, I am having a ASCII art which has lots of spaces in between two characters.

So I need to add the escape sequence for space in place of each space.

What is the Escape Sequence for space in iPhone SDK?

Comment: Using an escape sequence will make no difference to the app at run-time, the compiler simply translates them into literal space characters.

Comment: Thanks for your input. ya i know that but still which is the escape sequence for space?

Comment: Not sure but try `\ `? Or possibly the hex code which is `0x20`, however I don't know how to escape `0x20` to the actual space character.

Comment: JamWaffles: Thanks for your input. "\ " gives warning "Unknown escape sequence \040". What can be done?

Comment: What do you mean under escape sequence for space? Space is always space. Probably, you need unbrekable space character, or something similar?

Comment: In some languages `\s` is the escape sequence, however I'm not sure if the same applies to Objective-C.

Comment: \s shows unknown escape sequence.

Comment: @Nikolay O. : Thanks for your input. What exactly unbrekable space character means?

Comment: Why do you think you need to escape space characters?

Comment: @JeremyP : because my normal spaces are getting trimed in SMS API. What should I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [Non-breaking spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) (or [other unicode characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode)) instead:

```
NSString* body = @"t   \n e  \n  s \n   t\n";
body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"\u00A0"]; 
picker.body = body;
```